# XSLT add element at specific position

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

i want to transform an XML File as following:

This is my main original XML file:

```
<persons>
  <child name="child1"></child>
  <adult name="adult1"></adult>
  <child name="child2"></child>
  <child name="child3"></child>
  <COMMAND type="INSERT" file="otherchilds.xml"/>
  <adult name="adult2"></adult>
  <adult name="adult3"></adult>
</persons>
```

and there could be XML Files which should be imported by the XSLT whenever there is a tag COMMAND with an attribute "INSERT" in the main XML File.
I have to use XSLT 1.0

otherchilds.xml:

```
<childs>
  <child name="child4"></child>
  <child name="child5"></child>
<childs>
```

the two XML Files should transform to one XML File:

```
<root>
  <children>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
    <child3></child3>
    <child4></child4>
    <child5></child5>
  </children>
  <persons>
    <child name="child1"></child>
    <adult name="adult1"></adult>
    <child name="child2"></child>
    <child name="child3"></child>
    <child name="child4"></child>
    <child name="child5"></child>
    <adult name="adult2"></adult>
    <adult name="adult3"></adult>
  </persons>
</root>
```

So whenever a child is found, it should be added in the children element.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a result that doesn't have a root element? Is it ensured that the `name` attribute contains a value that can serve as an XML name?

Comment: This is only a part of my XML file. The real result will contain an root element. but i only wanted to post the interesting part.
Yes the name attribute will contain a value.

Comment: That's a *very* different question from what you posted originally. Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question at the beginning.
I have to use XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the XSLT code

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <children>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child" mode="el"/>
        </children>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child" mode="el">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

the input

```
<persons>
  <child name="child1"></child>
  <adult name="adult1"></adult>
  <child name="child2"></child>
  <child name="child3"></child>
  <adult name="adult2"></adult>
  <adult name="adult3"></adult>
</persons>
```

is transformed to the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<children>
   <child1/>
   <child2/>
   <child3/>
</children>
<persons>

   <child name="child1"/>

   <adult name="adult1"/>

   <child name="child2"/>

   <child name="child3"/>

   <adult name="adult2"/>

   <adult name="adult3"/>

</persons>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVR.

As for the changed requirements where there are additional elements to be loaded from a second file, the code can be changed to

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="persons">
        <children>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child | document(COMMAND[@type = 'INSERT']/@file)//child" mode="el"/>
        </children>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child" mode="el">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="COMMAND[@type = 'INSERT'][@file]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@file)//child"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

to handle that particular case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
Will this work too, when i add dynamically other XML files?

Comment: Where/how do you want to add other files? The code as posted should work if the `persons` element is contained elsewhere in an XML document as the identity transformation template would copy the rest of the nodes unchanged.

Comment: In my original XML File i haven an tag
    <COMMAND type="INSERT" file="filename.xml"/>

And when i find this Tag i import the File with:

    <xsl:template match="COMMAND">
      <xsl:if test="@type='INSERT'">
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="document(@file)"/>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

And in the imported File there could be "child" too.

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional samples and explain which result you want for the second XML sample, do you want to transform the `child` elements there as well, do you want to copy them unchanged? The template I have written acts on `persons` elements and its `child` child element, other `child` elements should not be affected.

Comment: @Cristan, well, that is a much more complex requirement but I have tried to adapt the XSLT to handle that case.